# losetup: cannot find an unused loop device

Tags: loop-device

I'm trying to create a loop device, and getting an error I don't understand:

```
# losetup -f  /media/2TB/sdb2-fix-file
losetup: cannot find an unused loop device
```

I have no loop devices setup. The output from `losetup -a` is null, and:

```
# ls -l /dev/loop*
crw-rw---- 1 root disk 10, 237 Oct  4 15:50 /dev/loop-control
```

Running `losetup -D` doesn't help at all.

Why is this occuring?

---

Below is the full `strace` output:

> ```
> # strace -fs80 losetup -f  /media/2TB/sdb2-fix-file
> execve("/usr/bin/losetup", ["losetup", "-f", "/media/2TB/sdb2-fix-file"], 0x7ffc6fe88c38 /* 164 vars */) = 0
> brk(NULL)                               = 0x55a51e754000
> access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
> openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
> fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=215090, ...}) = 0
> mmap(NULL, 215090, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f35d682e000
> close(3)                                = 0
> openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libsmartcols.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
> read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000n\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\210\341\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0008\0\10\0@\0\34\0\33\0\1\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
> fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=190600, ...}) = 0
> mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f35d682c000
> mmap(NULL, 2290720, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f35d640f000
> mprotect(0x7f35d643b000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
> mmap(0x7f35d663b000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2c000) = 0x7f35d663b000
> mmap(0x7f35d663e000, 1056, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f35d663e000
> close(3)                                = 0
> openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
> read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200\20\2\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\360s\37\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0008\0\n\0@\0G\0F\0\6\0\0\0\5\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
> fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2065840, ...}) = 0
> mmap(NULL, 3893456, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f35d6058000
> mprotect(0x7f35d6206000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
> mmap(0x7f35d6405000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1ad000) = 0x7f35d6405000
> mmap(0x7f35d640b000, 14544, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f35d640b000
> close(3)                                = 0
> mmap(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f35d6829000
> arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f35d6829740) = 0
> mprotect(0x7f35d6405000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
> mprotect(0x7f35d663b000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
> mprotect(0x55a51ccf5000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
> mprotect(0x7f35d6863000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
> munmap(0x7f35d682e000, 215090)          = 0
> brk(NULL)                               = 0x55a51e754000
> brk(0x55a51e775000)                     = 0x55a51e775000
> open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
> fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1687072, ...}) = 0
> mmap(NULL, 1687072, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f35d668d000
> close(3)                                = 0
> stat("/sys/block", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
> uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="svelte", ...}) = 0
> stat("/dev/loop-control", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0660, st_rdev=makedev(10, 237), ...}) = 0
> openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/loop-control", O_RDWR|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENODEV (No such device)
> stat("/dev/loop", 0x7fffae014c60)       = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
> stat("/dev/loop0", 0x7fffae014c00)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
> stat("/dev/loop1", 0x7fffae014c00)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
> stat("/dev/loop2", 0x7fffae014c00)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
> stat("/dev/loop3", 0x7fffae014c00)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
> stat("/dev/loop4", 0x7fffae014c00)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
> stat("/dev/loop5", 0x7fffae014c00)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
> stat("/dev/loop6", 0x7fffae014c00)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
> stat("/dev/loop7", 0x7fffae014c00)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
> open("/dev/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
> fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=3400, ...}) = 0
> getdents(3, /* 170 entries */, 32768)   = 4936
> getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
> close(3)                                = 0
> open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
> fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2997, ...}) = 0
> read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n# Copyright (C) 1996-2017 Free Software Foundatio"..., 4096) = 2997
> read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
> close(3)                                = 0
> open("/usr/share/locale/en_AU.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/util-linux.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
> open("/usr/share/locale/en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/util-linux.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
> open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/util-linux.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
> open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/util-linux.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
> write(2, "losetup: ", 9losetup: )                = 9
> write(2, "cannot find an unused loop device", 33cannot find an unused loop device) = 33
> write(2, "\n", 1
> )                       = 1
> close(1)                                = 0
> close(2)                                = 0
> exit_group(1)                           = ?
> +++ exited with 1 +++
> ```

Comment: In case it's an XY-problem: You can mount images files etc. directly and `mount` will take care of the loop device. You don't have to call `losetup` anymore, though I guess it still floats around in many tutorials on the web ...

Comment: I'm trying to create an overlay device for use with `dm-setup`. For others wondering, here's [what an XY problem is](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: Perhaps it needs the `loop` module loaded.. `# modprobe loop`.

Comment: I disagree with closing this. "off-topic as they are unlikely to help future readers" is false in this case. I had the same problem and the solution provided helped me.

Answer (score 17):

The kernel modules on disk were incompatible with the running kernel. I had updated my kernel and not yet rebooted.

[Running `modprobe loop`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396765/losetup-cannot-find-an-unused-loop-device?noredirect=1#comment708140_396765) gave me:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module loop not found in directory /lib/modules/4.9.51-1-MANJARO.
```

After rebooting, `modprobe loop` worked just fine.

Comment: So the problem was "modules on disk incompatible with running kernel"?

Comment: @dirkt Thanks, those were the words I wanted :)

Comment: @dirkt I've been reflecting on this, and wonder how I would have worked out that that was indeed the cause, given the symptoms I was experiencing. (Previous upgrades caused no issues). If you have any pointers, I'd be glad to hear them.

Comment: I figured this from your described solution ("after rebooting, it worked"). In general, compiling a kernel will change addresses etc., so that makes newly compiled modules incompatible with the old kernel. That's something you have to know, and it's easy to understand if you understand how assembly works. Which is also why you always reboot after you compile a new kernel. Without the information "I just had compiled a new kernel" it would have been hard to me to guess the problem. Which again shows it's very important to give *all* information about what you did when asking a question.